# Google Apps Script, Add cell A1 to A2 to display in A2, then Clear A1

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been struggling for a while.

I would like to put a value into A1.
then click a button to sum A1 and A2 and display the answer in A2.
then Clear A1.

This is the best I could come up with, P.S. its not working.

```
function addreward() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Farming & Staking");
  var oldcake = sheet.getRange("A2").getValue();
  var newcake = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();

 oldcake == newcake + oldcake;

 sheet.getRange("G7").clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the value:

```
sheet.getRange("A2").setValue(newcake + oldcake)
```

#### References:

- [Class Range - setValue(value) | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)

Comment: No problem. Also for reference, `==` is the [equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality), not the assignment operator (`=`). `oldcake == newcake + oldcake` will just return `false` (unless newcake is empty string) as it's comparing if the value of `oldcake` is the same as `newcake + oldcake`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the missing Piece Rafa Guliiermo.

complete code for the question:

```
 function myfunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 1");
  var A2 = sheet.getRange("A2").getValue();
  var A1 = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();

 sheet.getRange("A2").setValue(A1 + A2);

 sheet.getRange("A1").setValue("");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Name the script that is in the button that you created to "button":

```
function button() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A2').setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A2').getValue() + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').getValue());

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').setValue(0);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).